# How do I make two operations on the same array element?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have MongoDB `users` collection with the (simplified) document structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: 'John Doe',
  sportsList: [ // array of objects
    {
      name: 'football',
      level: 1500,
      levelHistory: [ // array of objects
        {
          from: 1450,
          to: 1500,
          date: Date
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'tennis',
      level: 1400,
      levelHistory: [ // array of objects
        {
          from: 1350,
          to: 1400,
          date: Date
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

I want to update the element of `sportsList` that has the `name === 'tennis'` like this:

- push a new element into `levelHistory`
- update the `level`
  So far I've managed to push a new element into `levelHistory` with this query:

```
await User.updateOne(
  {
    _id: userId,
    sportsList: {
      $elemMatch: { name: 'tennis' }
    }
  },
  {
    $push: {
      'sportsList.$.levelHistory': {
        date: Date,
        from: 1400,
        to: 1450
      }
    },
    // how do I set 'level: 1450' in the same query?
    // if I tried to use a $set: { 'sportsList.$.level': 1450 } mongoDB throws an error
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- pipeline update requires MongoDB >= 4.2
- map on the array
- if name is not tennis don't change the element
- else merge the element(embedded document) with a document that has the new level, and the new levelHistory (the concat of the old, with the new element)

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49e9)

```js
update(
{"_id": 1},
[{"$set": 
   {"sportsList": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$sportsList",
        "in": 
        {"$cond": 
          [{"$ne": ["$$this.name", "tennis"]}, "$$this",
           {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
            {"level": 1450,
             "levelHistory": 
                {"$concatArrays": 
                  ["$$this.levelHistory",
                  [{"from": 1400, "to": 1450, "date": 4}]]}}]}]}}}}}])
```

Comment: Works fine, I just put `$eq` instead of `$ne` inside `$cond`. Thanks!